# Unable to locate package openal-soft

Tags: linux, ubuntu, package, openal, openal-soft

I'm trying to install `openal-soft` on Ubuntu Focal, but without luck.

This is the package I would like to install:

https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/focal/openal-soft

**What I tried:**

```
sudo apt update
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt install openal-soft
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package `openal-soft` does not exist.

If you want to install the OpenAL SDK, use this command:

```
sudo apt-get install libopenal-dev
```

If you only need the lib on your system, run:

```
sudo apt install libopenal1
```

You also don't need to add the **universe** repository because it is enabled by default.

Comment: If it doesn't exist, then why is there a webpage about it, as posted in my question? Also, I need OpenAL Soft instead of regular OpenAL (both actually)

Comment: As you can read at "the Source page" https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/focal/openal-soft ... the package `openal-soft` is the "openal" source code → `openal-soft_1.19.1.orig.tar.gz`